# What is Mr. Kitty's gender?

Tags: character, south-park

I was wondering this for quite a while. Mr. Kitty is a male cat at the beginning of the episodes, but later on it's like he suddenly became a she.

(In the episode "Major Boobage" for cheesing they needed 2 male cats. In the other episode "Cat orgy" Mr. Kitty behaves like a female cat.)

Comment: http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Kitty   most probably shemale

Comment: @AnkitSharma that's the answer, you should post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mr.Kitty - SouthPark wikia](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Kitty) mentions the gender as **male**. This is the gender potrayed throughout the series, with the exception of a single episode.

The **only** episode where Mr.Kitty is depicted as a female is [Cat Orgy](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Cat_Orgy).

> Mr. Kitty would later have prominent role in "Cat Orgy", in which his/her gender has shifted back towards female and he/she is in heat. After attempting to have sex throughout the episode, Mr. Kitty assembles a massive group of male cats to come home with her. She then proceeds to get all the cat's high on catnip (which they snort like cocaine) and all the male cats proceed to take turns having sex with Mr. Kitty. Cartman and his babysitter Shelly Marsh were, needless to say, horrified.

Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_recurring_South_Park_characters#Mr._Kitty) mentions this -

> Although Mr. Kitty is indicated to be female in "Cat Orgy", there are examples of where he's portrayed as a male; in the season 12 episode "Major Boobage", the children experiment with Mr. Kitty's urine after learning that the urine of male cats can cause intoxication, indicating that Mr. Kitty is actually male.

Comment: Then why did they depict him a female in one episode?

Answer (score 4):

There are various references to the Mr Kitty's Gender which are as -

> - Mr Cartman always refers him as Mr. Kitty. Mr. is always used for male.
> - Mr. Kitty would later have prominent role in "Cat Orgy", in which his/her gender has shifted back towards female
> - Mr. Kitty's next real appearance would be in "Major Boobage", in which Cartman, Kenny, Kyle and Stan attempt to test whether or not
>     it's possible to get high off of male cat urine (Mr. Kitty is again
>     male in this episode).

(Source:[southpark.wikia.com](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Kitty))

It appears that changes are made from episode to episode, from Mr Kitty's nose color to Mr Kitty's gender. This is most probably due to a writer's mistake or just ignorance. We can still assume that Mr kitty might be bisexual or transgender, but I don't have confirmations from any canon sources.

Comment: I think the writer are well aware that they're making changes and are having fun with changing the cats gender. I would say the cat isn't bisexual or transgender.

Comment: the cat is a male, potrayed as a female only in a single episode. also, the nose colors have been part of a updated style with the fur also somewhat changed

Comment: @BenPlont that sounds weird to play with gender to make continuity errors.